# Iron-Router, what's the difference between redirect and render?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm wanting to make a 'before' hook for a certain page that will see if a user is signed in first and if not render/redirect to the sign-in page... now, should I use redirect or render for this?

I know this question is probably a more general question but I guess it would be helpful to know the difference between the two and when to use them..

Comment: Example code how to achieve this goal can be found here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452266/ironrouter-authorisation-controller/18506691#18506691

Comment: Difference between `render` and `go` is described more than precisely in IronRouter [docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic difference is that `render` will simply render the passed in template for whatever route the user landed on when the before hook was called, and `redirect` will change the route and render the template associated with the new route.

You can use either...just depends on what you want to accomplish. Sometimes you might want to allow the user to sign in from any page and then stay on that page...so, you would use a `render`. Other times, you want to send them to a sign-in route and then direct them to specific route following a successful sign-in...in that case, you'd perform a `redirect`.

Clear as mud?

Comment: So what's the difference between `Router.go` and `Router.redirect`?

Comment: Not sure there is a `Router.redirect` method. There is a `redirect` method on RouteController objects. This proxies to the `Router.go` method. Starting on line 331...https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/lib/route_controller_client.js

Comment: The guide says there is a `Router.redirect()` - http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#using-redirects

Comment: That is referencing the `redirect` method of the route function which is what  the OP was originally asking about (along with the `render` method). The `Router.go` method is a client-side method on the global `Router` object that you can use in a template helper or event to send the user to a different route.